# why 0000001 change to 1 when i export some number string to csv file in matlab?

Tags: matlab, csv, printf

I have a number string data column like this:

```
0004000
0000000
0000001
.....
```

But when i export them into csv file using `%s` as the format in `fprintf`, the column changes to:

```
4000
0
1
......
```

my code is generally like:

```
a=num2str(A,'%07d');
...
fprintf(f,'%s\n',a);
...
```

Comment: Do you want the data read as strings?

Comment: numbers with left zero-pad are dangerous... they can be mis-interpreted as Octal numbers and get trashed. is `045` really 45 with an extra zero, or is it an octal number, and really decimal 37?

Comment: @inquisitiveIdiot yes, i want it as string.

Comment: @MarcB 045 is really 45

Comment: @Jackie Looking at documentation I can't see a premade method for this. Have you considered loading it as a text file and then splitting it with the commas and then putting it in an array?

Comment: What do you mean with 'number string data' exactly? Could you maybe write down the exact code, so `A=[...]`?

Comment: @BasSwinckels A=[4000;0;1];

Comment: Please post runnable code, the code in your question results in a different output!

Comment: Are you trying to view the resulting csv in excel or something? that would somehow take away the leading 0s. try another text editor or simply open the csv with matlab.

Comment: @CiciYeah, I use excel to view the csv files...Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me, without the intermediate step with `num2str`, but directly with `fprintf`:

```
A=[4000;0;1]
f = fopen('foo.txt','w')
fprintf(f,'%07d\n',A);
fclose(f)
```

Comment: You're right. Output as txt would help. but anyhow i need to view it in excel, same problem happens.